# Upload data method in REST web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, upload

Do anyone know how can I write POST method in RESTful web service to upload data using java ?
I found that smartupload and commons.upload are just for web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some JAX-RS library, like [Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/), so you can write something like this:

```
@Path("/upload")
class UploadResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response upload(byte[] input) {
        // store input somewhere
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

}
```

So you will receieve your file is `byte[]`. You can also receive as InputStream:

```
@Path("/upload")
class UploadResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response upload(InputStream input) {
        // store input somewhere
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

}
```