# Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type) while uploading with wink

Tags: java, file-upload, jax-rs, apache-wink

I have a project which uses wink. It has several methods which use post/get and everything works fine except method which consumes `application/octet-stream` with POST. Calling this method causes error 415. It looks to me that it is jar or configuration issue. 
What can be checked to eliminate configuration/jar conflict?

Comment: A tip: post your code and an exception that you get in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

415 mean unsupported media type. Since you say that you have annotated the method with `@Consumes("application/octet-stream")`, I assume that you send a different media type.
Usually the file upload uses [a multipart media type.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages)

I suggest that you sniff the traffic (Fiddler is a really nice tool to do it) and see the real media type on the request.

Comment: The same code works fine in old project version. I post data with application/octet-stream (i select it in firefox poster add-on). Today I replaced byte[] to InputStream in method annotated with @Consumes("application/octet-stream") and it works. I would like to understand why...

Comment: What does the method return? Does it match the Accept header?

Comment: The function creates and returns some object. How can i check the Accept header? Here is annotation: 
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

Comment: It would be very nice if you place the code in your question formatted. Best way to check the header is to use sniffer like Fiddler. You can also stop in debugger in org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.

Comment: I will stop my investigation because of lack of time. Anyway, i solved the issue using your reply from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496023/upload-data-method-in-rest-web-service). Do you have any link, where i can read about Providers for byte[] and InputStream?

Comment: I guess the JSR311 is the only place. Section 4.2.4 contains the list of standard providers.