# Upload binary file with RESTful web service in Glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, rest, file-upload, jersey

I am trying to send a binary file (picture) to my RESTful web service running in Glassfish.
I have found code that supposed to do that in 
[Upload data method in REST web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496023/upload-data-method-in-rest-web-service)
and several other similar posts but neither work.
Here is my code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public String post( InputStream payload ) throws IOException
{
    return "Payload size="+payload.available();
}

@POST
@Path("bytes")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public String post( byte[] payload )
{
    return "Payload size="+payload.length;
}
```

The method that receives InputStream returns:

```
Payload size=0
```

The method that receives byte[] returns:

```
Error 500 - Internal Server Error
```

The Error 500 is caused by this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.typeIsKnown(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:110)
at com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker.isReadable(MoxyMessageBodyWorker.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:345)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:315)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:294)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:449)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
... 40 more
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I highly suggest you remove one of your tags to make room for "java"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM is working, but the payload.available() can not work here

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public String uploadStream( InputStream payload ) throws IOException
{
    while(true) {
        try {
             DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(payload);
            System.out.println(dis.readByte());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //Or you can save the inputsream to a file directly, use the code, but must remove the while() above.
  /**
    OutputStream os =new FileOutputStream("C:\recieved.jpg");
    IOUtils.copy(payload,os);
  **/
    System.out.println("Payload size="+payload.available());
    return "Payload size="+payload.available();
}
```

You will find the method indeed works, as it print some bytes. But payload.available() is 0.

Comment: Thanks Stony. I have seen this example before, but the problem is that the client is not sending MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA - it is sending MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, so this example is not working for me. Is there any way to change it to consume octet-stream?

Comment: I think the APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM is working, but the payload.available() can not work here.  I just edit my answer, pls check it.